# Partially disable File Output Node in compositing?

Tags: node-editor, interface, compositing-nodes

A File Output node like this ...

[image]

... will generate several images at once (here: A001.png, ..., A250.png and B001.png, ..., B250.png and C001.png, ..., C250.png, all in folder D).
For reasons involving different render border settings, I would like to sometimes only render A and B, say, sometimes B and C, sometimes only A, and so on.

**Q:** Is there a way to "elegantly" switch off generation of individual outputs (I think they are called subpaths)? The only way I have found so far is to disconnect the individual inputs. In order to facilitate disconnecting and reconnecting, I already added reroute nodes nearby. More "elegant" would be a checkbox or the like (perhaps even animate-able)

Comment: You can't disable/mute sockets as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you output to multiple png files, there is no downside to having separate File Output node for each instead of the one with many inputs. You can then select the ones you want to temporarily disable and press <kbd>m</kbd> for mute. If you had multilayer EXR that would be a problem, but since you only need to output separate PNGs, that should work fine. Disconnecting inputs also seems elegant enough for me.

You can also use this new node Switch (Blender 2.80) that you can find in Add -> Layout -> Switch

[image]

It gives you a checkbox and you can hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to hide unused inputs when you have it selected as you can see I have done on the first one for it to be more compact. It seems to be animate-able, but I have not tested it.

Comment: Oh, I saw th eSwitch node, but thought it could not really switch off (i.e., switch to constant white or other colour at best). In other words, I learned about input hiding only now, thanks :)